# Chatbot UI to scroll for long conversations in next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, jsx

I am trying to make it so that as the conversation gets longer, there will be a scrolldown so that the user can scroll up to see previous messages and i want to make it so that the messages dont end up overlapping with the input box and the button to send the message. As my code is right now the conversation will overlap the input box and start going even lower, making it so that the whole page needs to be scrolled down. Within my layout.js I've added my navigation bar and as you can see by my code I have a left column for new chats. I want to make it so that only the section between the input box to where the first message is rendered on the screen scrollable. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Home page.js

```
'use client';
import { useState } from 'react';
import SendChatButton from '@/components/buttons/SendChatButton';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faPenToSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

export default function Home() {
  
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [conversation, setConversation] = useState([]);
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const clearInput = () => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    setConversation([...conversation, inputValue, "Hi"]); // Add FashionFinder's message after each user message
    setInputValue('');
  };
  
  return (
    <div className='m-0 w-full h-screen grid grid-cols-7' style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 60px)' }}>
      <div className='bg-gray-200 col-span-1 left-0 p-1'>
      <button className='w-full rounded-lg p-2 hover:bg-gray-100 flex justify-between items-center'>
        <span className='font-semibold text-sm'>New Chat</span>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPenToSquare} />
      </button>
      </div>
      <div className='col-span-6 flex flex-col items-center justify-center'>
        {isSubmitted ? (
          <div className='absolute top-20 w-5/6 p-2'> 
            {conversation.map((message, index) => (
              <div key={index} className='p-2'>
                {index % 2 === 0 && (
                  <>
                    <p className='font-bold'>You</p>
                    <p className='font-md'>{message}</p>
                    <hr className='bg-black'/>
                  </>
                )}
                {index % 2 !== 0 && (
                  <>
                    <p className='font-bold'>FashionFinder</p>
                    <p className='font-md'>{message}</p>
                    <hr className='bg-black'/>
                  </>
                )}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className='mx-auto'>
            <img src="/FFlogo.png" />
            <h1 className='text-4xl mx-auto font-semibold text-center'>
              Tell us what you're looking for
            </h1>
            <h2 className='font-semibold text-xl text-center p-2 mb-20'>
              We'll find it for you
            </h2>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="absolute bottom-5 w-5/6 flex justify-center h-16">
          <input
            type="text"
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
            className="w-2/4 p-4 border rounded-xl outline-none z-10"
            placeholder="Message FashionFinder..."
          />
          <SendChatButton inputValue={inputValue} clearInput={clearInput}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```